# Why does Chrome add a query string parameter after included Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript file in my HTML page that is included like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript\pages\page.js"></script>
```

yet in the chrome network debugger, when i look at what is loaded, it has:

```
http://localhost:12639/javascript/pages/page.js?_=1556081859333
```

This is problematic as im not wishing this particular file to bypass caching.
If it makes a difference, the html file is being loaded through an AJAX call.

The value for the field looks to me like a timestamp. Or even just a random number. Any guesses on how it gets there?

Edit: Below is the AJAX call code which will retrieve the HTML result:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'process.php',
            type: 'POST',
            datatype: "json",
            async:true,
            data: {
               //some data
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            },
            success: function (data) {
              $("#somediv").html(data);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Are you using a library to make the AJAX call? I know jQuery use to do something similar...

Comment: @Jack im a using a standard jQuery AJAX call

Comment: Assuming you're passing `cache: false` in your `$.ajax` call? Edit: Could you include the JavaScript with how you're making the ajax call?

Comment: @Jack added in the code. Its pretty basic AJAX call. Im not using `cache:false` but was the first idea that came to mind. I may explicitly state it to cache but i dont think thats the issue here... Edit: i just noticed the datatype. that may have something to do with it being set to JSON

Comment: @MartinZeitler thank you i wasnt aware of the right terminology to search

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, the issue is jQuery. From their [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
:

> **cache** (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp')
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser. ***Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with HEAD and GET requests.*** It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL that has already been requested by a GET.